# Resampling Pandas DataFrame by hour and plotting a stacked bar chart using Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly, bar-chart

I have a pandas dataframe as below

| MAC Address | ts | Parameter1 | Parameter2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| af3d116c | 2021-05-05 21:58:45 | 20 | 50 |
| bffe479a | 2021-05-05 21:58:48 | 22 | 52 |
| c3a8fe37 | 2021-05-05 21:58:52 | 21 | 53 |
| af3d116c | 2021-05-05 21:58:58 | 27 | 50 |
| bffe479a | 2021-05-05 21:59:16 | 23 | 51 |
| c3a8fe37 | 2021-05-05 21:59:50 | 28 | 52 |
| af3d116c | 2021-05-05 22:08:32 | 30 | 49 |
| af3d116c | 2021-05-05 22:16:30 | 27 | 55 |
| bffe479a | 2021-05-05 22:31:37 | 20 | 53 |
| c3a8fe37 | 2021-05-05 22:52:49 | 32 | 52 |
| af3d116c | 2021-05-05 23:22:02 | 41 | 58 |
| bffe479a | 2021-05-05 23:44:31 | 37 | 62 |
| bffe479a | 2021-05-05 23:45:12 | 29 | 58 |
| bffe479a | 2021-05-05 23:49:28 | 34 | 41 |
| c3a8fe37 | 2021-05-05 23:52:47 | 47 | 56 |

I would like to resample the data frame and finally plot stacked bar charts (preferably using plotly) representing the total number of rows recorded per hour and color coded based on MAC Address.

Below is a representation of how I want it to be visualized. (Sorry, it is not using the data listed above, but gives an indication on how I want it to be. Each bar represents an hour eg: 22:00 till 23:00 separated by color representing MAC addresses.)

[image]

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by 'resample'? Do you mean group by?

Comment: I don't mind how the resampling is done. It can be using groupby or the resample method in pandas or something else. My aim is to have the stacked bar plot as mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do groupby with `pd.Grouper(key='ts', freq='1h')` to 'resample' the dataframe by hour. `size` will get you a frequency count of the MAC addresses:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

data = {'MAC Address': {1: 'af3d116c', 2: 'bffe479a', 3: 'c3a8fe37', 4: 'af3d116c', 5: 'bffe479a', 6: 'c3a8fe37', 7: 'af3d116c', 8: 'af3d116c', 9: 'bffe479a', 10: 'c3a8fe37', 11: 'af3d116c', 12: 'bffe479a', 13: 'bffe479a', 14: 'bffe479a', 15: 'c3a8fe37'}, 'ts': {1: '2021-05-05 21:58:45', 2: '2021-05-05 21:58:48', 3: '2021-05-05 21:58:52', 4: '2021-05-05 21:58:58', 5: '2021-05-05 21:59:16', 6: '2021-05-05 21:59:50', 7: '2021-05-05 22:08:32', 8: '2021-05-05 22:16:30', 9: '2021-05-05 22:31:37', 10: '2021-05-05 22:52:49', 11: '2021-05-05 23:22:02', 12: '2021-05-05 23:44:31', 13: '2021-05-05 23:45:12', 14: '2021-05-05 23:49:28', 15: '2021-05-05 23:52:47'}, 'Parameter1': {1: 20, 2: 22, 3: 21, 4: 27, 5: 23, 6: 28, 7: 30, 8: 27, 9: 20, 10: 32, 11: 41, 12: 37, 13: 29, 14: 34, 15: 47}, 'Parameter2': {1: 50, 2: 52, 3: 53, 4: 50, 5: 51, 6: 52, 7: 49, 8: 55, 9: 53, 10: 52, 11: 58, 12: 62, 13: 58, 14: 41, 15: 56}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['ts'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ts'])

plot_df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='ts', freq='1h'), 'MAC Address']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: "count"})
```

This will result in:

|  | ts | MAC Address | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-05-05 21:00:00 | af3d116c | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-05-05 21:00:00 | bffe479a | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-05-05 21:00:00 | c3a8fe37 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-05-05 22:00:00 | af3d116c | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-05-05 22:00:00 | bffe479a | 1 |
| 5 | 2021-05-05 22:00:00 | c3a8fe37 | 1 |
| 6 | 2021-05-05 23:00:00 | af3d116c | 1 |
| 7 | 2021-05-05 23:00:00 | bffe479a | 3 |
| 8 | 2021-05-05 23:00:00 | c3a8fe37 | 1 |

You can then plot this as you wish. Eg:

```
fig = px.bar(plot_df, x="ts", y="count", color="MAC Address", title="MAC Addresses per hour")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. 
I was used to groupby operation but new to pd.Grouper. Thanks for introducing this concept to me.